# Why doesn't the pandas apply method have an axis=None option to apply a function to the whole dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There seems to be a gap in the pandas API (IMHO/YMMV) in that there is no way to chain operations (in a fluent style) that operate on the whole dataframe.

e.g. `a.op1.op2.op3...`

The apply method takes a function and an axis argument and applies the function to either rows or columns accordingly.  What I think is missing is an axis=None which would then mean that the function applies to the whole dataframe.  This would then allow for operations, including structural modifications (e.g. dropping rows, columns, renaming, index changes etc) to be chained in such a fluent style.

There is a hack to accomplish this.

If a is a dataframe then...

```
a.groupby(lambda _:0).apply(lambda x:...
```

... means that the x in the applied lambda is set to each group of the groupby successively but there is only one group created so a function applied to that one group effectively becomes a function applied to the whole dataframe. However this is a bit clunky and has a drawback is that ***sometimes*** the groupby creates a new level in the index (but ***sometimes*** it doesn't and that is hard to predict).

Have I missed a method in the API or is there a less clunky way to achieve this?

Comment: Look at applymap to apply a function to each cell of the dataframe.

Comment: @ScottBoston That's not really what I want, kinda in the opposite direction.  I want the x in the lambda to be the dataframe, not a component of it.  I will try to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't the pandas apply method have an axis=None option to apply a function to the whole dataframe?

I don't know why pandas developer decided not to allow None as an axis key, but I suppose that it is that way because there are two options to achieve what you expected. The first one you have become already yourself aware of is usage of the `pandas.DataFrame.pipe` method.

Another option as an alternative to using pandas own `.pipe(func, ...)` method will be to put all your functions working on pandas DataFrame objects into a `chainOfPandas` class as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
print('',end=' ========== \n')
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'colA':['A']})
print(df,end=' \n ========== \n')
class chainOfPandas:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
    def f1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ... do something here on self.df ...
        self.df['colF1'] = ['F1'] # example: add a column
        return self
    def f2(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ... do something here on self.df ...
        self.df['colF2'] = ['F2'] # example: add a column
        return self
    def f3(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ... do something here on self.df ...
        self.df['colF3'] = ['F3'] # example: add a column
        return self
    def get_df(self):
        return self.df

df = chainOfPandas(df).f1().f2().f3().get_df()
print(df,end=' \n ========== \n')
```

making it possible to chain functions working on pandas dataframes with

### df = chainOfPandas(df).f1().f2().f3().get_df()

Here the output the code above prints providing evidence that this approach works as expected as each of f1, f2, f3 adds a new column to df:

```
 ========== 
  colA
0    A 
 ========== 
  colA colF1 colF2 colF3
0    A    F1    F2    F3 
 ==========
```